# POCO dev-release v1.5.3 compilation failure

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, poco-libraries

I am building a cross-platform c++ project and I am evaluating various libraries that might help me get the job done. One of them is POCO. Seems like it provides everything I need and I wanted to try it.

Context:

- OpenSSL for windows (http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), both platforms installed in "C:\OpenSSL-Win32" and "C:\OpenSSL-Win64";
- mysql connector for c++ 1.1.4 x86;
- I have both VS2010 and VS2013 installed on my machine;
- I decided to go with VS2013 even though there is no official release yet to support it because the project may take a while until the first release and meanwhile if there is any problem in POCO, it might be fixed by then;
- OS: Win8.1 x64;
- Target platform is x86 - for now;

Anyway, all good, until trying to compile. It looks like for each toolset version, there is a batch file. For VS2013 (v12) there wasn't any. I manually created it:

```
    @echo off
    if defined VS120COMNTOOLS (
    call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat")
    buildwin 120 build shared both Win32 samples
```

and named it `build_vs120.cmd` following the pattern.

In `buildwin.cmd` I edited the paths of OpenSSL and mysql to point to the correct location:

```
    set OPENSSL_DIR=C:\OpenSSL-Win32
    set MYSQL_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.4
```

That's all I edited in `buildwin.cmd`. Everything else looks normal to me.

Now, I opened Power Shell and started `build_vs120.cmd`. `CppUnit` projects are both going well, but on `Foundation` project fails:

```
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ++++ Building [Foundation_vs120.vcxproj]
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.30723.0
    [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 8/23/2014 8:56:02 AM.
         1>Project "D:\Proiecte\cpp\commons\POCO\Foundation\Foundation_vs120.vcxproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
         1>InitializeBuildStatus:
             Touching "obj\debug_shared\Foundation.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741819. [D:\Proiecte\cpp\commons\POCO\Foundation\Foundation_vs120.vcxproj]
         1>Done Building Project "D:\Proiecte\cpp\commons\POCO\Foundation\Foundation_vs120.vcxproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

           "D:\Proiecte\cpp\commons\POCO\Foundation\Foundation_vs120.vcxproj" (build target) (1) -> (CustomBuild target) ->
             C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741819. [D:\Proiecte\cpp\commons\POCO\Foundation\Foundation_vs120.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:01.54
```

I am pretty lost. I tried to dig for this error but there wasn't much info about it. Any idea what's going on? Have I done something wrong? Is there any missing dependency I forgot to install or setting to make to Visual Studio?

Thanks,
DC

Comment: Googling for "-1073741819 cmd.exe" lead me to this thread: http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-error-code-1073741819_topic14138.html

Comment: @nodakai - thanks! :-) my problem was particular related to visual studio. There isn't any custom build step set there to identify the command line and when I click on the error, it points to "Microsoft.Cpp.targets" file. Which is where I am getting lost. I was thinking that there might be someone with some experience in POCO or any case like this with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact ... it's a problem with my Visual Studio installation:

- I tested POCO libraries compilation on another machine (Win7/x64) and it worked fine - full version;
- I tried to add custom build steps for problematic machine (pre/post and any type of custom build step - starting with simple "dir", copying a file or just kicking off a new executable) and they all crashed with the same message. Compilation failed for POCO and for a dummy project created only for this test.

I tried to reinstall VS2013, to apply the sp3 - but they all failed in the same way. Closing this matter as it is no longer related with POCO library.